# $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin(\sin x)}{x}$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

Can someone suggest how to solve this limit?

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(\sin x)}{x}$$

If I substitute $y=\sin x$ then $\sin(\sin x)=\sin y$ while $x=\arcsin y$. Then the limit becomes $$\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{\sin y}{\arcsin y}$$

but this form is more complicated than the first one...

Comment: What is $senx$? Do you mean $\sin x$?

Comment: Wonderful, I read this sen already a few times, thought I missed out on something.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom $\operatorname{sen}=\sin$ is a notation which, for some reason, is particularly common in Italian high-school books (it stands for "seno", which is the Italian name of the sine function). The odd fact is that, as far as I know, it completely disappears at university, so it remains like this teen-age crush you live with from 17 to 19, and then you never hear about it anymore.

Comment: you're so right...i beg your pardon but I can't help to stop writing sen

Comment: @G.Sassatelli In addition to Italy, $\operatorname{sen}$ is used throughout Latin America, where the function also goes by the name *seno*.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Is even more absurd if you think to calculators which are NOT translated in Italian :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint** multiply top and bottom by $\sin x$ and break into a product of two limits.